# React testing library - how to send "anchorEl" as prop?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I have a component that displays material-ui menu, and gets the anchorEl from the parent component.
I want to test this component, but I don't know what should I send as the anchorEl prop

my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Menu, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';
import { PopulatedNode, NodeMenuItem } from '../types';

interface Props {
  node: PopulatedNode;
  items: NodeMenuItem[];
  anchorEl: (EventTarget & HTMLButtonElement) | undefined;
  onClose: () => void;
}

const NodeMenu = (props: Props) => {
  const { node, items, anchorEl, onClose } = props;

  return (
      <Menu
        id="node-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={!!anchorEl}
        onClose={onClose}
        data-testid="node-menu"
      >
        {items.map(({ onClick, disabled, label }) => (
          <MenuItem
            key={label}
            onClick={onClick}
          >
            {label}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Menu>
  );
};

export default NodeMenu;
```

I want the menu to be open, so anchorEl must be of type `EventTarget & HTMLButtonElement`

How can I simulate it?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass any valid DOM element, i.e.:

```
const mockAnchorEl = document.createElement("button");
```

Comment: It worked for me. But I have to put it in the beforeEach method

Answer (score 0):

Create a mock as follows and pass it as props

```
const mockAnchorEl = {
  current: document.createElement("button")
}

render(
<Menu
        id="node-menu"
        anchorEl={mockAnchorEl }
        keepMounted
        open={!!mockAnchorEl }
        onClose={onClose}
        data-testid="node-menu"
      >
)
```